# Error when using cv2.findContours

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I tried to find contours for image, but it gives an error.

My code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('star.jpg',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
```

error is:

> `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\OpenCVContore.py", line 5, in <module> contours,hierarchy,thresh = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2) error: ........\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:236: error: (-215) step[dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags) in function cv::Mat::create`

I am using `Python 2.7` `OpenCV 2.4.7,2.4.11`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm using OpenCV 3.0, but when I tested your code with a valid file it worked. When I changed the file name to a file that didn't exist, I got a very similar error to your error. Make sure the image file is in the same directory as the script and that the file name is an exact match.

Comment: no problem in image read . may problem in "contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)" this line . why this is not work in opencv 2.4.7,2.4.11 and 2.4.12 with python 2.4.9

Comment: Change the file name to a file that doesn't exist and see what error you get. I bet it won't be with `imread`.

Comment: Yes `imread` doesn't throw any exceptions on error, you get all kind of funny error messages later. I'm using my own Python wrapper around it because of that.

Comment: I am tried this code in python 3.4 and opencv 3. Working fine | what is wrong for this error in python 2.x versions . Please can show some valid code for python 2.x and opencv 2.4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by updating my python version to 3.4 and opencv version 3. But cannot find real solutions for this. Why python 2.x versions not fully support for openCV